# How to add VSCode-avy keybindings to VSCode, given that one already has VSpaceCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Does anybody know how to add the keybindings for the avy timer in VSCode with the extension VSCode-Avy https://github.com/likern/vscode-avy, given that one has also VSpaceCode installed?

I tried

```
{
    "key": "space+j+j", 
    "command": "findThenJump.initiate", 
    "when": "sideBarFocus && !inputFocus && !whichkeyActive"
}
```

in my keybindings.json but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it.
Go to the keyboard shortcuts (with Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S or Ctrl+Shift+P and search for Open Keyboard Shortcuts (not the json one) and then search for "findthenjump". Now the available keybindings for VSCode-avy should appear.

Select the keybinding that you want to change and press Enter. Then just type the keybinding